# Wordpress - How to trigger all routine functions and hooks after creating a new post from customized function

Tags: php, wordpress

I am very new (actually my 1st attempt) to wordpress plugin coding part. From tutorials available on net, I created my custom function to create a new post (in this case it's also new post type - "question", which has been already made available by AnsPress plugin).

Relevant part of my function is like -

```
<?php
function AddQuestionToAnsPress($question_title, $question_content, $answer_content, $subject_id, $exam_id) {
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    $path .= "/wp-blog-header.php";
    require($path);
    $question_title = strip_tags($question_title);
    $category_id = $subject_id;
    $category = array($category_id);
    $tag_subject_id = $subject_id;
    $tags = array(25, $tag_subject_id);
    wp_set_current_user(26);
    $user_id_for_question = 26;
    $question_array = array(
        'post_title' => $question_title,
        'post_author' => $user_id_for_question,
        'post_content' => $question_content,
        'post_type' => 'question',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'comment_status' => 'open'
    );
    $question_post_id = wp_insert_post($question_array);
    $question_permalink = get_permalink($question_post_id);
    wp_set_post_terms($question_post_id, $category, 'question_category');
    wp_set_post_terms($question_post_id, $tags, 'question_tag');

    $anspress_link = $question_permalink;
    return array('anspress_link' => $anspress_link, 'question_post_id' => $question_post_id);
}
?>
```

At present, this function is not added as plugin or in theme. Instead I am using it from a separate PHP file. This function does the primary work for me, i.e. to create a new post with post type "question". **But, the problem is, my function is unable to trigger any other plugin (and their relevant activities) which are triggered after creating a new post.**

For e.g. I have installed [NextScript SNAP plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/social-networks-auto-poster-facebook-twitter-g/) in my wordpress blog, which autopost, to my facebook page, the newly created posts (but only when the post is created from wordpress itself).

So, how should I modify my function or **what should I add to my function, so that it can auto-detect all the fucntions/hooks/filters which should be triggered soon after creating new post?**